# Как обьединить два массива из разных запросов?

Tags: mysql, массивы, laravel-5.8, querybuilder

Массив с комментариями

```
    "data" => array:2 [▼
0 => array:7 [▼
  "id" => 2
  "content" => "Количество символов в поле Текст комментария должно быть не меньше 10."
  "created_at" => "2020-10-05 12:03:35"
  "updated_at" => "2020-10-05 12:03:35"
  "user_id" => 1
  "post_id" => 1
  "login" => "JonBobby"
]
1 => array:7 [▶]
```

Массив с оценками комментариев

```
array:1 [▼
0 => array:3 [▼
    "comment_id" => 2
    "count_likes" => 0
    "count_dislikes" => 1
  ]
]
```

Есть два запроса к БД. 1й получает все комментарии одного поста, 2й подсчитывает лайки и дизлайки к каждому комментарию выборного поста.

Как объединить эти два массива в один чтобы можно было без заморочек вывести данные во вьюхе? а то я уже день бьюсь и все равно ничего не получается.

Модель RatingComment

```
/**
 * Получаем Лайки и Дизлайки комментариев поста
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 */
public function getVote(int $post_id)
{
    return $this->query()
        ->selectRaw(
            'comments.id as comment_id,
            count(CASE WHEN rating_comments.type = "like" THEN 0 END) as count_likes,
            count(CASE WHEN rating_comments.type = "dislike" THEN 0 END) as count_dislikes')
        ->leftJoin('comments',
            'comments.id',
            '=',
            'rating_comments.comment_id')
        ->where('rating_comments.post_id', $post_id)
        ->groupBy('rating_comments.comment_id')
        ->get();
}
```

Модель Comment

```
/**
 * Получаем все комментарии Одного поста
 *
 * @param int $post_id
 */
public function getAllCommentInPost(int $post_id)
{
    return $this->query()
        ->join('users',
            'comments.user_id',
            '=',
            'users.id')
        ->select('comments.*',
            'users.login as login')
        ->where('comments.post_id', $post_id)
        ->orderBy('comments.created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5);
}
```

Comment: Объедините запросы в один.

Comment: Я относительно недавно начал работать с laravel и у меня эти два запроса в разных моделях + пока что у меня есть проблемы в составлении сложных запросов